# How to set the base image as small image for the product progmatically?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am using following code to set the base image as the small image of the product.
Before running the code I have following information

```
---
----
[image] => /s/a/santat.jpg
[small_image] => 
[thumbnail] => /s/a/santa-300.jpg
---
```

### ---

```
<?php
require 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                        ->addAttributeToFilter( 'sku', array( 'in' => array( '01Santa') ) );

foreach ($products as $product)
{   
    if (!$product->hasImage()) continue;
        if (!$product->hasSmallImage())
        {   

            try{
                $product->setSmallImage($product->getImage());
            }
            catch(Exception $e) 
            {               
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
        $product->save();       
}
?>
```

Once the code has run I have following if I print

```
print_r($product);

[image] => /s/a/santa.jpg
[small_image] => /s/a/santa.jpg
[thumbnail] => /s/a/santa-300.jpg
```

But still in admin no image is set as small image why?(I am using multi website setup)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <?php
    require 'app/Mage.php';
    Mage::app();

    $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                            ->addAttributeToFilter( 'sku', array( 'in' => array("004XmasVacGrnShtrs") ) );                      

    foreach($products as $product)
    {
        $productId = $product->getId();
        echo "<br>";    
                //load the product
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId("14")->load($productId);
            //get all images
        $image = $product->getImage(); //Get product base image
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(array($product->getId()), array('small_image'=>$image), 14); //14 is store id    
    }
    echo "done";

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change code

```
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
$mediaGallery = $product->getMediaGallery();
if (isset($mediaGallery['images'])){
    foreach ($mediaGallery['images'] as $image){
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(array($product->getId()), array('small_image'=>$image['file']), 0);
        break;
    }
}
```